# Projecting a vector onto its span

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, projection

I am trying to show that for a vector, $v$ in $R^n$ with $||v|| = 1$, that its projection onto it's span $\Omega = span(v)$ is given by $(v \cdot x)v$ for any $x \in R^n$.

I know how to do it through geometry, but I need to show it by solving directly for the point $z$ in $\Omega$ closest to $x: min_{z \in \Omega} ||x-z||^2$.

I've tried to do this by subbing in $cv$ for $z$ to make the expression: $||x - cv||^2$ and expanding it as a dot product to give me: $(x - cv) \cdot (x - cv) = x \cdot x - cv \cdot x - cv \cdot x + cv \cdot cv = ||x||^2 - 2c(v \cdot x) + c^2||v||^2$ but this is where I'm getting stuck and not seeing how to get from there to $(v \cdot x)v$.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, and if possible, an extension of this to to have $v^{(1)}$ and $v^{(2)}$ be two orthonormal vectors and $\Omega = span(v^1, v^2)$ to have its projection be $(v^{(1)} \cdot x)v^{(1)} + (v^{(2)} \cdot x)v^{(2)}$.

Comment: Not true for projection.  Only works for *orthogonal* projection onto $\Omega$.

Comment: Interpret your expression for the dot product as a function of $c$, differentiate, set to zero, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, @GerryMyerson.  I took your approach, but I'm still missing the $v$.  If I differntiate with respect to c, I get $-2(x \cdot v) - 2c$. Setting it equal to 0, I get $c = (x \cdot v)$, which is still missing $v$ outside of the parentheses. Any thoughts?

Comment: $c=x\cdot v$, but what you're looking for is $z$, not $c$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thought about that right after I sent the last comment - thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Good. Write it up, and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to find the answer with some help:

After taking the dot product and expanding, I ended up with $||x||^2 - 2c(v \cdot x) + c^2||v||^2$.  I'm trying to optimize over c, so the first term can drop since it doesn't contain $c$, and since $||v|| = 1$, then $||v||^2 = 1$, so that term drops.

That left me with $- 2c(v \cdot x) + c^2$, which I treated as a function of c and differentiated it with respect to c to optimize: $\frac{d}{dc} - 2c(v \cdot x) + c^2 = - 2(v \cdot x) + 2c$.

Setting it to equal zero: $0 = - 2(v \cdot x) + 2c$ -> $-2c = - 2(v \cdot x)$ -> $c = (v \cdot x)$.

We can then plug the that back into $||x - cv||^2$ to get $||x - (v \cdot x)v||^2$